# LEFT JOIN and duplicate results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an sql statement as follow:

```
    SELECT  s.sp_id,s.synopsis,s.logline,s.user_id,s.bin_status,s.sp_order,s.sp_down_count,s.sp_name,
            `users`.firstname as `firstname`,`users`.lastname as `lastname`,s.status,
            `users`.email as `email`,`users`.phone as `phone`,`users`.address1 as `address1`,
            `users`.address2 as `address2`,`users`.`r_group`, view_coverages.grade,coverages.comments  

    FROM s 
    LEFT JOIN `users` ON `users`.user_id=s.user_id  
    LEFT JOIN view_coverages ON view_coverages.sp_id=s.sp_id 
    LEFT JOIN `coverages` ON `coverages`.sp_id=s.sp_id  

    WHERE $email_filter lower(s.synopsis) like '%$search_word_fix%'
    OR lower(s.sp_name) like '%$search_word_fix%'
    OR lower(s.logline) like '%$search_word_fix%'
     OR lower(coverages.comments) like '% $search_word_fix %'
    ORDER BY view_coverages.grade DESC
```

when I display the results I get a lot of duplicates.
I would like to display the results of the search where s.sp_name is not duplicate.

Comment: You're getting getting duplicates in your results because somewhere you have data that doesn't have a unique join.  In order to _find_ that (so this can be corrected), we need some sample data and results, and possibly what it is you're trying to accomplish...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Select only the unique, non-duplicate results by changing your `SELECT` to `SELECT DISTINCT`.
2. `GROUP BY s.sp_name` but you will need to perform an aggregate function on all of the other fields you are selecting.

As I am sure you can't average or sum a person's name, address, phone number, etc., you should probably just try option 1 (`SELECT DISTINCT`). If you have a non-unique field in your otherwise duplicate row, you will need to `GROUP BY` every field except the unique field; use an aggregate function (i.e., `SUM`, `AVG`, etc.) on the remaining unique field(s).

Comment: I used select DISTINCT its still displaying duplicates

Comment: You mean nothing changed or zero rows were returned? If nothing changed, what field(s) is NOT duplicated in the duplicate rows?

Comment: no its still displaying duplicates. SELECT DISTINCT s.sp_id,s.synopsis,s.logline,s.user_id,s.bin_status,s.sp_order,s.sp_down_count,s.sp_name etc...

Comment: Okay, so in a row that has "John Doe" twice, which specific fields are *different* between those two rows? Are the phone numbers different? The statuses? Etc.

Comment: Sounds to me like you have duplicate data, then. Otherwise if you have a one-to-many relationship on those joined tables you run the possibility of duplicate data for any parent rows.

Comment: Okay, what you're doing doesn't really make sense. Why are you returning the ID values if you don't use them? And which coverage or view coverage row do you want to keep around. We can't answer your question completely without more information.

Comment: I am not returning the ID value you asked me which one is different. the rows are not repeated. the reason I am using left join coverages is because it contains fields that i need to display in results coverages.comments is one of them

Answer (score 1):

Ty this:

```
SELECT  s.sp_id,s.synopsis,s.logline,s.user_id,s.bin_status,s.sp_order,s.sp_down_count,s.sp_name,
            `users`.firstname as `firstname`,`users`.lastname as `lastname`,s.status,
            `users`.email as `email`,`users`.phone as `phone`,`users`.address1 as `address1`,
            `users`.address2 as `address2`,`users`.`r_group`, view_coverages.grade,coverages.comments  

    FROM s 
    LEFT JOIN `users` ON `users`.user_id=s.user_id  
    LEFT JOIN view_coverages ON view_coverages.sp_id=s.sp_id 
    LEFT JOIN `coverages` ON `coverages`.sp_id=s.sp_id  

    WHERE $email_filter lower(s.synopsis) like '%$search_word_fix%'
    OR lower(s.sp_name) like '%$search_word_fix%'
    OR lower(s.logline) like '%$search_word_fix%'
     OR lower(coverages.comments) like '% $search_word_fix %'
  ADD --->       group by s.sp_name  
    ORDER BY view_coverages.grade DESC
```